# How to change java Dimension to android?

Tags: java, android

I'm having one Java file which contains the `Dimension` property as like,

```
static int cbto(Dimension panelSize) {
    int Wp = panelSize.width;
    int Hp = panelSize.height;
}
```

I have used the package as,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
```

Now I want to convert this Java code into Android. How could I change this? In which class is equilaent to `Dimension` in Android?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses dimensions in a resource file.

Add a file to your values folder inside the res folder, call it dimensions.xml.

Inside, add rows like this:

```
<dimen name="panel_width">150dp</dimen>
```

Make sure to use lower-case names and no numbers or spaces.
Also, always use dp for normal sizes & sp for font sizes.

For more info, look at this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

Hope this is what you were looking for :)